# filtering and sorting XML with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to find a way of filtering results in a XML file as I would normally do with MySQL and PHP.

Assuming my query is "select ID, NAME from USERS order by ID ASC" , how would I run the same query on my XML file if the file structure was something like:

<user>
  <ld>1</id>
  <name>Bob</name>
</user>

...

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

## Examples

Given this XML and PHP:

```
$xml = <<< EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<userlist>
  <users>
    <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Bob</name>
    </user>
    <user>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>David</name>
    </user>
  </users>
</userlist>
EOT;

$x_obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

- `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC`

  ```
  $result = $x_obj->xpath('//user');

  function cmp($a, $b)
  {
    if ( $a->id > $b->id) return -1;
    if ( $a->id < $b->id) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
  usort($result, cmp);
  ```
- `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2`

  ```
  $result = $x_obj->xpath('//user[id=2]');
  ```
- `SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=2`

  ```
  $result = $x_obj->xpath('//user[id=2]/name');
  ```
- `SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='Bob'`

  ```
  $result = $x_obj->xpath('//user[name="Bob"]/id');
  ```

The result will be a simple array.

Live on codepad.org (***20:10 GMT+1: currently down***): http://codepad.org/LSo2YX37

Comment: Hey again ComFreek, how do I then print / echo this data?

Comment: @Tim The result is a simple array ;)